# Webcam not detected in Ubuntu 20.04, Samsung 350V5C. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, webcam, samsung

As the title says, the integrated webcam isn't detected in my installation of **Ubuntu 20.04** (tested on Pop! OS, LMDE, Mint and Linux MX, all had the same issue) on a **Samsung 350V5C** (from 2012 or so). I first tested with cheese and guvcview, then looked for it with `lsusb`, `lspci`, `lshw`, tried activating with `modrobe uvcvideo`, and did a hardware probe. The camera worked on previous installations (can't remember which though). There is no option for webcam in BIOS settings.
A hw probe I found online for that laptop model lists the camera as **SC-13HDL11939N**, and it seems it *should* work, but I can't get the system to recognize it.

Has anyone been able to use this webcam? or, What are the steps to follow towards a solution?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Another Samsung laptop, about the same generation, has the same issue (can't remember the model, ahven't got it with me right now). I opened both, nothing seems disconnected physically (didn't measure though), odds are that it's a diver / kernel issue (¿?).